# Fetch parse table data in dictionary, filter and do math operation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am independent developer started learning programming few months back. Currently I am trying to find a way to get business rating and show it to the user when needed. I am using Parse.com as my backend and have the parse table which has the following column (keys):

Rating (type: Number) - using float values

BusinessName (type: String)

BusinessReviewText (type: String)

Now, I am retrieving this data as:

```
//Declaring empty dictionary
    var businessReview = [[String:Float]]()
    var businessReviewText = [[String:String]]()

//Parse query
 var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Business")
        query.whereKey("ratingBool", equalTo: true) // just checking which businesses have been reviewed by users
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                for object in objects as! [PFObject!]{

                    var bN:AnyObject = object["BusinessName"]!
                    var bR: AnyObject = object["Rating"]!
                    var bRT: AnyObject = object["BusinessReviewText"]!

                    self.businessName.addObject(bN)
                    self.businessRating.addObject(bR)
                    self.businessRatingText.addObject(bRT)   
                    self.businessReview.append(["\(bN)":bR as! Float])
                    self.businessReviewText.append(["\(bN)":"\(bRT)"])
                }
// Gives me Key: BusinessName and its rating value: floatValue as output
                println("\(self.businessReview)") // I get the output as [[businessA: 4.0], [businessA: 4.0], [businessB: 5.0], [businessC: 5.0], [businessC: 3.5], [businessC: 3.5], [businessD: 3.5]]

// Gives me Key:BusinessName and its review Value:ReviewText as output
                println("\(self.businessReviewText)") // I get the output as [[businessA: Good job], [businessA: High], [businessC: Awesome service! A++], [businessC: Good service!], [businessC: Good but can improve], [businessD: "NO REVIEW"], [businessD: Ok ]]
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have the following question:
1. How can I now filter each business name with it's key value so that I can perform math for example,
To get the rating for businessC: (Addition of all businessC ratings/businessC.count) i.e: ((5+3.5+3.5)/3) = 4

Note: In this, I don't know which businesses rating the user is checking (for ex: user may search Chinese restaurants and he can see all the rating for Chinese restaurants business rating) on screen. So I would love to have all the business reviewed in one result (is it the right thing to do?)

2. Is this the right way to get the ratings? If not, what is the alternative? Any tutorial out there?

Sorry if I am too descriptive. But while searching on stack overflow I sometimes find it difficult to understand the questions people ask. So I try to provide as much info as needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "filter each business name with it's key value"  Do you want to filter the actual name of the business?  or to filter BY the business name?  Can you include a for instance?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if the above is not clear. But I don't know specific key values that user has on screen. That is the reason I said I want the code to calculate reviews for all the business in this. So it won't matter which business the user is checking on screen. He can see the final output something like: Name: businessA, Rating: 5 (overall after calculating the average rating) and Business review text if he clicks on specific business. Similar to eBay/Amazon and all the other places you see review.

Comment: You could create two NSDictionarys. The first with the keys of type NSString and the values of type NSArray (e.g. Key:BusinessName, Value:Array of Ratings). The second with the keys of type NSString and the values of type Integer (e.g. Key:BusinessName, Value:Average Rating). Then, while iterating over the businesses insert the rating in to the array corresponding to the businessName key in the first dictionary. Next, enumerate the first dictionary, and iterate of the objects in the array in the value. Finally, average the ratings for that specific business and insert the average...

Comment: in to the second dictionary corresponding to the businessName key. Now you have a dictionary of businessNames and their values are the average. Your problem could be solved multiple ways but, this is just food for thought and I think the time complexity would just be O(n + n)=O(2n)=O(n).

Comment: @Jonathan, I am still learning. I have worked with arrays but this is the first time I am really working with Dictionaries. Enum I will have to look into what it is first. Can you please give the code sample for what you have mentioned above? I will accept the answer once I am able to get it working. Thank you.

Comment: Scratch that, it would probably be O(n + n^2)=O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

You could create two NSDictionarys. The first with the keys of type NSString and the values of type NSArray (e.g. Key:BusinessName, Value:Array of Ratings). The second with the keys of type NSString and the values of type Integer (e.g. Key:BusinessName, Value:Average Rating). Then, while iterating over the businesses insert the rating in to the array corresponding to the businessName key in the first dictionary. Next, iterate over the keys in the first dictionary, and iterate of the objects in the array in the value. Finally, average the ratings for that specific business and insert the average in to the second dictionary corresponding to the businessName key. Now you have a dictionary of businessNames and their values are the average.

Your problem could be solved many ways, but this is just food for thought. Someone on this site may be able to give you a more efficient way.

Pseudocode:

```
Dictionary[String, Array] allRatings
Dictionary[String, Integer] averageRatings

for each business
    if allRatings does not contain business.name
        Array ratings
        ratings add business.rating
        allRatings set key equal to business.name and set value equal to ratings
    else
        Array ratings = allRatings get array for bussiness.name
        ratings add business.rating
end for each

for each key called businessName in allRatings
    Array ratings = allRatings get value for businessName

    int average = 0

    for each rating in ratings
        average += rating
    end for each

    average /= ratings.count

    averageRatings set key equal to businessName and set value equal to average
end for each
```

In theory, the time complexity for this should, I think, be O(n^2). It's decent but not that great.

*P.S. I feel like there might be something wrong with this but, I wouldn't know for sure unless I tested it.*